# Done Toolbar on UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uitoolbar

So I have a button on a page when clicked I am opening up a picker view. I have populated the picker view with the months. I added a toolbar but whenever I try to select it just scrolls the picker view to the top.

```
    monthPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height- monthPicker.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: monthPicker.frame.size.height))
    monthPicker.delegate = self
    monthPicker.dataSource = self
    monthpickerData = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
    monthPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //
    let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.monthdoneButtonAction))
    let barAccessory = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: monthPicker.frame.size.width, height: 44))
    barAccessory.barStyle = .default
    barAccessory.isTranslucent = false
    barAccessory.items = [flexiblespace,btnDone]
    monthPicker.addSubview(barAccessory)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is confusing! How are you creating the monthPicker, based on the size of the monthPicker? You're not adding the monthPicker nor the btnDone to the view's subviews. You are adding another button called btnDone2 to the bar accessory items, but I don't see where you're creating btnDone2...

Comment: Accidentally added that 2. Fixed that. The button selection is where I add the monthPicker to the view. Didn't include that because it didn't seem to affect the toolbar not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like UIPickerView is not letting its children receive touch events. If you are showing this in conjunction with UITextField you can use it's inputView and inputAccessoryView to acheive the same. Alternatively you can create a top level container UIView to hold both toolbar and picker view like this:

```
    let picker = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - 260, width: view.frame.width, height: 260))

    // Toolbar
    let btnDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.monthdoneButtonAction))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelClick))

    let barAccessory = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: picker.frame.width, height: 44))
    barAccessory.barStyle = .default
    barAccessory.isTranslucent = false
    barAccessory.items = [cancelButton, spaceButton, btnDone]
    picker.addSubview(barAccessory)

    // Month UIPIckerView
    monthPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barAccessory.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: picker.frame.height-barAccessory.frame.height))
    monthPicker.delegate = self
    monthPicker.dataSource = self
    monthpickerData = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
    monthPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    picker.addSubview(monthPicker)
```

Comment: This worked great. The only thing I change was I set the monthPicker height as 216. It wasn't at the bottom of the screen otherwise.

Comment: It also helped me. Thanks :)